# Is there a re-usable github action to display the results of my Karate framework tests on the main build summary page?

Tags: github, action, karate

I am running Karate framework tests to do integration testing in a Github repo.

My boss would like the main build summary to show a quick summary of the tests kind of like this (but this does not work)

```
  - name: Karate Test Result Report
    uses: dorny/test-reporter@v1
    if: success() || failure()    # run this step even if previous step failed
    with:
      name: Karate Test Results            # Name of the check run which will be created
      path: "/app/target/surefire-reports/*.xml"    # Path to test results
      reporter: java-junit        # Format of test results
      fail_on_error: true
  - uses: mshick/add-pr-comment@v2
    if: always()
    with:
      status: ${{ job.status }}
      message-success: '✔️ Unit tests passed'
      message-failure: '❌ Unit tests did not pass'
```

Is there a way to add graphical output to the main build summary page that shows how many of the Karate tests passed / failed?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that the Karate project would like to do in future, but for now, pull-requests are welcome.

Here is a thought. Since Karate can [output the JUnit XML format](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#parallel-execution) when you use the `Runner` builder API you should be able to use any GitHub action that supports that format, and it is widely supported. For example I found [this](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/junit-report-action), but there may be better ones.